# R: ggplot with a cyclic curve

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataframe:

```
  Cycle   Time   WSS
  <chr> <dbl> <dbl>
 1 C1        5  5.3
 2 C1       30  4.2
 3 C1       60  3.8
 4 C1      120  3.4
 5 C2        5  4.7
 6 C2       30  3.9
 7 C2       60  3.1
 8 C2      120  2.6
 9 C3        5  5.1
10 C3       30  4.3
11 C3       60  3.6
12 C3      120  2.9
13 C4        5  4.3
14 C4       30  3.8
15 C4       60  3.2
16 C4      120  2.6
```

Where I plot Time(x) against WSS(y). I have used ggplot like this:

```
   MyDF %>%
      ggplot(aes(Time, WSS))+
      geom_smooth(size=1, se = TRUE)+
      facet_grid(~Cycle)
```

which looks like the following [curve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQRnM.png). I would like to have it as one continuous curve however with the cycles depicted under the x axis. Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You will need to compute a single numeric variable combining time and cycle.  E.g. if time 0 equals time 120 of the previous cycle, and `Cycle` is a factor, `120*as.numeric(Cycle) + Time`.  You'll want to change the axis labels as well; I'm not sure the details of that in `ggplot2`.

Comment: When publishing a post, include data using the `dput` function

Comment: Is it correct to assume that 120 is a period (endpoint) of the cycle? What do you mean by *depicted under the x axis*? Do you need labels for time or time *and* cycles?

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. See the code below.

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
        Cycle = rep(paste0("C", 1:4), each = 4),
        time = rep(c(5, 30, 60, 120), 4),
        WSS = rnorm(16)
    ) %>% 
    mutate(
        cycle.time = df$Cycle %>% str_extract("[1-4]") %>% as.numeric(),
        cycle.time = (cycle.time - 1) * 120 + time
    )

df %>%
    ggplot(aes(cycle.time, WSS, col = Cycle)) +
    geom_line() +
    scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0:3 * 120), labels = paste0("C", 1:4))
```

[image]

P.S
I allowed myself to generate a WSS just to illustrate it quickly.

Comment: I would suggest to add `library()` part to the code. It must be `library(dplyr); library(stringr); library(ggplot2)`. Or just a `library(tidyverse)`